# How can I make a window fit its contents in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is some sample code. The window does not resize (python3.2, on a Mac, from macports). Is there a way I can modify it so that it resizes the window? Thanks.

```
import tkinter
import time

root = tkinter.Tk()
can = tkinter.Canvas(root, width = 10, height = 10)
can.pack()

for i in range(10):
    can.configure(width = i * 50, height = i * 50)
    root.update()
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Your code works with python 2.7 on a mac. Are you *certain* the exact code in your question doesn't work? When you run it, are you manually resizing the window after it first starts up?

Comment: Seems to work for me using a Mac with 2.6.6 or 3.1.3. Unfortunately, I don't have 3.2.

Comment: @BryanOakley Could it be that the OP's Python 3.2 doesn't have tkinter? http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: I do have tkinter. The program "works" but the window is not resized. I checked that the window is indeed resized correctly with older versions of Python (python2.7). It is probably a bug (or feature) of the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
import tkinter
import time

root = tkinter.Tk()
can = tkinter.Canvas(root, width = 10, height = 10)
can.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
can.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
can.grid()

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

for i in range(10):
    can.configure(width = i * 50, height = i * 50)
    root.update()
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Same behaviour. No improvement. Probably a bug in my version of tkinter. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't have access to such a low version of python, so I unfortunately I can't really test any of my suggestions, but have you tried using the root.minsize() function? It accepts a height and a width just like root.configure.